# How to write a query that has multiple count columns

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
select patient.Gender,count(patient.Gender) 
as gender_count from patient
where patient.Gender=(select distinct patient.Gender from patient);
```

I get the error

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Error is self explanatory use in instead of = also how many genders do you have that you need a sub query at all and are they fluid? Also group by would seem more appropriate.(can't really tell since you have not told us what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Now I understand my mistake. Also I had 3 genders M, F, T in my database. I was trying to accomplish the task using only 1 query instead of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
select Gender, count(Gender) as gender_count from patient
group by Gender;
```

Your group by itself will combine the repeated values and give you count. Also, you dont need `patient.` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Query is

```
 SELECT patient.Gender,COUNT(patient.Gender) AS gender_count
 FROM patient
 GROUP BY patient.Gender
```

here we grouped data by Gender and applied Count on them.